# Set page size in QWebView in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I write a python script using PyQt4 to crawl web pages including AJAX. It worked, but it can only get 'one-screen' page which I think relates to the screen resolution. I run the script on  CentOS server which doesn't have X environment. I use **Xvfb** and do the following settings:

```
$ Xvfb :100 -screen 0 9000x9000x24 &
$ export DISPLAY=:100
```

but it didn't help to get more web info.

I'm new to PyQt4. Is there a method to set the QWebView size to enlarge the display window size?

Any manual about QtWebkit is also appreciated.

The following is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8


import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl, SIGNAL, QSize
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage, QWebView, QWebSettings

class WebPage(QWebPage):

    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, message, lineNumber, sourceID):
        sys.stderr.write('Javascritp error at line number %d\n' % (lineNumber))
        sys.stderr.write('%s\n' % (message, ))
        sys.stderr.write('Source ID: %s\n' % (sourceID, ))


class Crawler(QApplication):

    def __init__(self, url):
        super(Crawler, self).__init__(sys.argv)
        self.url = url
        self.web_view = QWebView()
        self.web_page = WebPage()
        self.web_view.setPage(self.web_page)
        self.web_frame = self.web_page.currentFrame()

        print 'Before connecting'
        self.connect(self.web_view, SIGNAL('loadFinished(bool)'), self.loadFinished)
        print 'After connecting'

        print 'Before loading'
        self.web_frame.load(QUrl(self.url))
        print 'After loading'

    def loadFinished(self, ok):
        self.web_page.setViewportSize(self.web_page.mainFrame().contentsSize())
        print 'In callback, before writing'
        with open('jd.txt', 'ab+') as fp:
            fp.write(self.web_page.currentFrame().toHtml().toUtf8())
        print 'In callback, after writing'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://www.360buy.com/product/707047.html'
    crawler = Crawler(url)
    sys.exit(crawler.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the web_page to it's actual size by using the setViewportSize method:

```
self.web_page.setViewportSize(self.web_page.mainFrame().contentsSize())
```

Trigger scroll event after loadFinished is emitted:

```
def loadFinished(self, ok):
    js_scroll = "window.scrollBy(0, 200);"
    self.web_page.mainFrame().documentElement().evaluateJavaScript(js_scroll)
```

Although I'm not sure how the page you're loading is working actually, you may need to wait until the ajax request is completed after the scroll event for the data to appear on the page.

Comment: I use the method **QWebView.setViewportSize**, however, there seems no effect. In CenOS Server, I still got the same web page info as before although I set the size to a very large value. Then I tried to run the script in Xorg environment on my laptop and added `self.web_view.show()` statement to see the effect. However, got the same and the window size didn't change……

Comment: have you added the setViewportSize line to the method triggered by the loadFinished signal? When you say it didn't show the whole page, you mean that for the actual window displayed has scrollboxes, but you wan it to be displayed in one piece right?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the code to add `setViewportSize()` in the method triggered and couldn't get the whole info of the web page. My problem is as you said. I want to get all info of the web page and if browsing the web page in a browser, it has scrollboxes actually. The code above could get part of the webpage.

Comment: I tried **selenium** to crawl all info of a web page. After I use **Xvfb** to set a large screen resolution and then I can get all info of the web page. But it didn't fit this situation. I think if using QtWebKit to do this, it maybe relates to the size of the window displayed and could being set by some API. But I'm new to PyQt and couldn't get more materials about QtWebKit except for the API manual

Comment: setViewportSize can help you if you want to create a screenshot of the whole page, because it will make the QWebView widget as large as the page visually is. but under information if you mean you didn't get the whole data on the page, and by that you mean getting self.web_page.currentFrame().toHtml().toUtf8() didn't return everything? have you tried getting the data from web_page.mainFrame() ? also execute the load method on self.web_view rather than on self.web_frame

Comment: I tried but still got part info of the web page. I used **web_view** to get the page and set **setViewportSize** before and after the method triggered by the **loadFinished** signal…… The web page has some AJAX code and can only display part of info until moving the scrollbar to trigger the AJAX event.

Comment: have you tried triggering the scroll event by yourself with javascript after the page is loaded? I'll add that code piece to the answer..

Comment: I wanted to trigger the scroll event but I don't know how to implement that. [QtWebKit Module](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtwebkit.html) is the only material I can get. Please give me some tips on how to add such event.

Comment: I tried to trigger the scroll event, but it seemed that the scroll bar would be moved after all statements in `loadFinished()` had been executed and no AJAX events seemed to be parsed. In [QWebFrame](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebframe.html) [QWebPage](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebpage.html) I tried some signals, but got nothing…… Thanks anyway.